# CodeCache is getting full after moving to OpenJDK 21

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-codecache

After switching to OpenJDK 21, we noticed the growing CodeCache.

[image]

This is the application running with G1GC without the FullGC, we don't have this problem with ParallelGC. I come across this issue: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8290025
If I understand it correctly, CodeCache Sweeper was disabled and the cleanup job is only in Full GC in G1GC?

Affected parts of Segmented CodeCache: **non-profiled nmethod** and **profiled nmethod**

Have you encountered the same problem in G1GC with OpenJDK 21?

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Growing CodeCache is not a problem per se, as long as an application works correctly and performance stays fine. CodeCache cleanup can be potentially invoked on every nmethod allocation, depending on the amount of free space left and the values of `-XX:SweeperThreshold` and `-XX:StartAggressiveSweepingAt`.

Comment: `StartAggressiveSweepingAt` is by default - 10% ... Maybe, I'm just a bit scared of switching off JIT compiler because od full CodeCache. I don't understand the algorithm of sweeping right now: [full-codecache-graph](https://github.com/petrbouda/codecache-investigation/blob/main/full-codecache.png)
It's full for 3 days and then it deallocates half of the size and I don't see the reasong. Same workload, no Full-gc.

Comment: jcmd <pid> Compiler.CodeHeap_Analytics - [output](https://github.com/petrbouda/codecache-investigation/blob/main/Compiler-CodeHeap_Analytics%20-stripped.txt) - I had to strip method names.

No free blocks for `non-profiles nmethods`
`not entrant  =   109464k, nBlocks_notentr  = 123561,     91.857% of capacity`
and lot of `nMethod (deopt)` in the output